# To Split JSON result

Tags: jquery, json

Iam using Jquery in ASP.NET

My JSON Result is in the following format

> **2@2@POD @POL @IsTransshipmentPort**

I want to Split the values and bind to Dropdown list how can i split Json Result.

```
   select: function (e, i) 
    { 
       $('#<%=hddnPortTerminal.ClientID%>').html(i.item.val); 

    }
```

The Result is Bind to HiddenFiled, How can i split These data which is in HiddenFiled and take it to other Dropdown?

Iam not getting any idea, can any one please help

Comment: `2@2@POD @POL @IsTransshipmentPort` does not look like JSON.

Comment: You could split the string back by using a defined separator, which, in your case is `@`, by calling `string.split('@')`. If it were JSON, you won't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode("@", $result);
```

Of course, saying "I want to split a string" is meaningless.

Comment: explode is a PHP funciton, the OP does not mention the use of PHP, only javascript (actually, they mention ASP.Net so unlikely PHP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string then you can use the `split()` function (strangely enough).

Something like this:

```
var x = "2@2@POD @POL @IsTransshipmentPort";

var splits = x.split("@");//assuming you want to split on "@"

for(var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++){
    alert(splits[i]);//you can do what you want with each value here
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcL8r/) (warning: 5 alert popups)

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: @7stud: I don't do PHP, nor is there any mention of it in the question